# How to use ByVal Target As Range So it applies to multiple cell and is not dependent on previous

Tags: excel, vba, event-driven

The objective of this code is so every time cell E6:E36 changes from "Yes" or to "Enter Non Final Action Taken Date" I want it to run my macro.

It works only when E6 is marked to match the next value. How do I make it so it is not dependent on the previous cells value?

I'm new with VBA so I'm a bit lost. Any help would be greatly appreciated. See current code below:

```
  Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As range)

Application.EnableEvents = False 'pervent triggering another change event
    On Error GoTo ERR_HANDLING

 If Not Intersect(Target, range("E6:E36")) Is Nothing Then
Select Case range("E6,E7,E8,E9,E10,E11,E12,E13,E14,E15,E16,E17,E18,E19,E20,E21,E22,E23,E24,E25,E26,E27,E28,E29,E30,E31,E32,E33,E34,E35,E36")
Case "Yes": EnterDate_of_last_Submission

End Select
End If

 If Not Intersect(Target, range("E6,E7,E8,E9,E10,E11,E12,E13,E14,E15,E16,E17,E18,E19,E20,E21,E22,E23,E24,E25,E26,E27,E28,E29,E30,E31,E32,E33,E34,E35,E36")) Is Nothing Then
Select Case range("E6,E7,E8,E9,E10,E11,E12,E13,E14,E15,E16,E17,E18,E19,E20,E21,E22,E23,E24,E25,E26,E27,E28,E29,E30,E31,E32,E33,E34,E35,E36")
Case "Enter Non Final Action Taken Date": EnterNonFinal_Date

End Select
End If

On Error GoTo 0
ERR_HANDLING:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source, Err.Description, Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContex

    End If
End Sub
```

[image: Example of Problem]

Comment: You need to loop through that range.

Comment: What do you mean by "How do I make it so it is not dependent on the previous cells value?" when you are monitoring the change in the contents of the cell?

Comment: @SJR Basically If the cell that is above is not selected to "Yes" say E5 when i select the cell below it say E6 to "Yes" it will not trigger a event. But If E5 is equal to "Yes" it will run the macro when the value of E6 is changed to "Yes". So as of now it is dependent on the prior one, do you know how to avoid this?

Comment: @BigBen How would I go about doing that?

Comment: If `Target` is E6 then `Target.Offset(-1)` is E5. Not sure I understand 100%. You might also need to use `SelectionChange` to capture the value when the cell is selected (i.e. before it is changed). Or possibly not...

Comment: `Dim rng as Range`, then `For Each rng in Intersect(Target, Me.Range("E6:E36"))`.

Comment: @SJR I added a Image to help explain the problem let me know if that makes it more clear. I changed the cell references up for illustration purposes.

Comment: @BigBen Where would i enter that in the code i tried but it did not work, i probably placed in wrong spot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop here and compare cell-by-cell, something like the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As range)
    Dim rngToCheck as Range
    Set rngToCheck = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("E6:E36"))

    If rngToCheck Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    On Error GoTo SafeExit
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim rng as Range
    For Each rng in rngToCheck
        Select Case rng.Value
            Case "Yes"
                EnterDate_of_last_Submission
            Case "Enter Non Final Action Taken Date"
                EnterNonFinal_Date
        End Select
     Next

SafeExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Most likely `EnterDate_of_last_Submission` and `EnterNonFinal_Date` should be rewritten to take a `Range` parameter, namely the cell the date is entered in (which it looks like would correspond to `rng.Offset(,1)` with your current setup.

Comment: Slight problem I just noticed. It works if the only items you change on the sheet are the drop down cell E6:E36 as referenced in code. But if you change any other value and then go back to run the macro it no longer works? I looked into it on forums and it has something to do with EnableEvents but im not sure how or what i should change to make other edits on the page not trigger events but at the same time still allow you to go back and run macros as the check mark changes E6:E36.

Comment: You need to keep the error handling that you already had.. that's what the `...` references in my code.

Comment: Ya i have that but if i make a change anywhere else on the sheet and then go back to change the cell that runs the macro it no longer works?

Comment: See the edit... also in the Immediate Window, type `Application.EnableEvents = True` and hit Enter.

Comment: Basically making a tracker, and if i click a drop down the macro will run perfectly within that range. But if i go to A2 for example and change the date and then go back to select a macro cell it will no longer run? Ill attach another photo on the thread

Comment: What are you changing the dropdown to?

Comment: Got it, I was toggling between Yes and Enter Non Final Action Taken Date. Appears to work now! Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Hey another error came up, so i am trying to apply the same logic to other cells that change on different sheets. I get this error: "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment". Is there a limit to how many ranges you can have it check? It worked for the first two sheets but when I try to add more to the range it doesn't.

Comment: @johncap - perhaps ask that as a new question. As a side note - it can get slightly frustrating for an answerer if you accept, then unaccept, then accept, then unaccept an answer :-)

Comment: I apologize, new to the forum. Appreciate all of your assistance.